How to get incoming call information while on the other call Android
I am building app supporting for the voip call.
On the app, when there is no active call, I can get the incoming call information using TelephonyManager and PhoneStateListener.
But when I am on the voip call, If personal call(SIM call) income, I can't get the incoming call information. After finishing the Voip call, I can get the incoming call information.
I am going to add features like this:
when I am on the voip call, if personal call income and accept it, I a going to hold the voip call.
